# POST array is empty when containing a file

Tags: php, forms, post, file-upload

I have a simple HTML form containing a file input. When the form is submitted without a file, printing the `$_POST` array shows me all of the data submitted. When a file is submitted, however, `$_POST` doesn't print out any of the submitted data.

Can somebody tell me why? This is my code:

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST);
?>
<form action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="myfile">Video File:</label>
    <input type="file" name="myfile" />
    <br /><br />
    <label for="mytitle">Title:</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="mytitle" size="55" maxlength="60" />
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="Submit Video for Approval" />
</form>
```

Comment: Depends on what function you're using to print the data... Try var_dump()

Comment: Why it depends? I haven't heard of this yet

Comment: @ArtaexMedia What? It's not a problem printing the data, it's the fact that the data isn't even there. `echo $_POST['title'];` gives me nothing either.

Comment: @DannyF247 could you be reaching `post_max_size` when you upload that file (that file being very close/over that limit)? This would be a very edge case and PHP should error out AFAIK anyway. Let me see if I understood clearly: you've entered something into `mytitle` and it didn't show up, did it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script seems fine. Please check your server configuration. Perhaps you exceed POST limits (set with post_max_size in php.ini)

Comment: Silly me, you're right. My file was exceeding the max POST size, so I guess all my other data was truncated as well.

Comment: Yes, sorry I was going to earlier but it said to wait 10 more minutes, and I completely forgot about it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [$_FILES](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) to access the uploaded files.

```
var_dump($_FILES); // Your uploaded files
var_dump($_POST);  // Your entered data
```

Comment: I understand I need to use `$_FILES` to access my file, but what about the other data in my form?

Comment: The other data *should* be in `$_POST`

Comment: You can still use $_POST with $_FILES together