# Multiple file upload form not posting

Tags: php, forms, post, file-upload

I am trying to build a multi-file uploading script for a few image galleries of mine, and I've come across a strange error.

Since I have *a few* galleries, which all have their own directories, I want to be able to tell the script where to put my uploaded files. Thusly I added a few radio buttons to satisfy this need. When I upload the files, they get processed some code, supplied along with the form below:

```
<?php
/* upload.php */
if(isset($_GET['upload']) && isset($_POST['loc'])){
    $loc = $_POST['loc'];
    $dir = getDir($loc); //Returns the directory to upload to, -1 on invalid input
    if($dir != -1){
        $i = 0;
        foreach($_FILES as $file){
            foreach($file as $key=>$v){
                foreach($v as $f){
                    $files[$i][$key] = $f;
                    $i++;
                }
                $i=0;
            }
        }
        foreach($files as $file)
            uploadImage($file,$dir);    //Uploads files to proper directory
    }else{
        print "Bad user! Don't alter things!";
    }
}elseif(!isset($_POST['loc']) && isset($_POST['submit'])){

    /* I should end up here if no location is supplied and the form is submitted */

    print "Enter a location please";
}
?>

<form action="upload.php?upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <label for="file">Image:</label>
   <input type="file" name="files[]" id="file" multiple="multiple" required><br />
   <label for="dir1">Directory 1</label>
   <input type="radio" name="loc" id="dir1" value="1"><br />
   <label for="dir2">Directory 2</label>
   <input type="radio" name="loc" id="dir2" value="2"><br />
   <label for="dir3">Directory 3</label>
   <input type="radio" name="loc" id="dir3" value="3"><br />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

The file parsing itself works, thus I won't supply code for the called functions. What doesn't (always) work is the posting of my form. If I try to upload 35 files, everything works fine and my images gets uploaded to the correct directory. If I try to upload 40 files the script doesn't run. Since I can see that `$_GET['upload']` is set I can deduce that `$_POST['loc']` is not. Which is strange, since the form obviously submitted as `$_GET['upload']` was set, as stated by the form's action. "Enter a location please" isn't posted when I get this error, so I know that `$_POST['submit']` isn't posted either. If I `var_dump` any of the two variables it returns `NULL`.

I've already increased `upload_max_filesize`, `max_file_uploads` and `max_execution_time` in my php.ini file, so the issues shouldn't be there, and I'm all out of ideas. So my question is why this happens and what I can do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I look around and found a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115247/post-array-is-empty-when-containing-a-file). I tried applying the solution suggested in the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14115270/1257387), which seem to have fixed the issue.